# How can you move up the paging buttons

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, xslt

The default location of the Paging buttons is all the way down(see picture below). Is there a way to move them over all the way UP, so that users don't need to scroll down every time they want to change page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JavaScript. Here you need to handle three events

1. Page Load
2. Next Page Click
3. Previous Page Click

On all these events execute following function

```
jQuery('#WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container').append(jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ2').clone());
```

Where `scriptPagingWPQ2` is the `div` element id of the pagination controls.
And `WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container` is the `span` element id of the All Items... control.

You can find these ID using browser developer tools.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I am bit puzzled on how to implement this. do I need to add this code inside a Content Editor Web part in the list view?

Comment: I tried this on a CEWP : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#WPQ2_ListTitleViewSelectorMenu_Container').append(jQuery('#scriptPagingWPQ2').clone());</script> but it doesnt work